# logstash email plugin install giving error

Tags: email, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to send email alert from logstash if a string match but I got error when I am going to install logstash-output-email plugin on logstash 1.4

```
sudo bin/plugin install logstash-output-email
Can only install contrib at this time... Exiting.
```

I have no idea do I need to install that plugin or its already install

**Edited** 
After upgrade to 2.0 Logstash my configuration look like this

```
output {

elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
    if  "ERROR" in [message]  {
    email  {
        options => [ "smtpIporHost", "smtp.gmail.com",
         "port", "587",
         "userName", "test@gmail.com",
         "password", "password",
         "authenticationType", "plain",
         "starttls","true"
           ]
            from => "test@gmail.com"
            subject => "logstash alert"
            to => "test@gmail.com"
            via => "smtp"
            body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
       }
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

any idea and get error in logstash logs

```
:message=>"Unknown setting 'options' for email", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2015-11-02T12:59:24.598000+0000", :message=>"Error: Something is wrong with your configuration."}
```

Comment: `sudo bin/plugin install` does not work in Logstash 1.4. [Logstash's Plugin Ecosystem](https://www.elastic.co/blog/plugin-ecosystem-changes) was introduced with the release of v1.5.0. Do you have the possibility to update?

Comment: I will check that tomorrow to upgrade to 1.5

Comment: I am getting error now after upgrade to 2.0 logstash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am getting error now after upgrade to 2.0 logstash

Yes, because `options =>` is deprecated and no longer available in logstash v2.0. Please see the [v2.0 email plugin docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.0/plugins-outputs-email.html). That's why it says `:message=>"Unknown setting 'options' for email`.

You need to migrate all values inside the `options =>` part into new settings. Something like this might work:

```
email  {
     port           =>    "587"
     address        =>    "smtp.gmail.com"
     username       =>    "test@gmail.com"
     password       =>    "password"
     authentication =>    "plain"
     use_tls        =>    true
     from           =>    "test@gmail.com"
     subject        =>    "logstash alert"
     to             =>    "test@gmail.com"
     via            =>    "smtp"
     body           =>    "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
}
```

Take a look at both, the [old v1.5 email docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-outputs-email.html#plugins-outputs-email-options) and the [new v2.0 email docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.0/plugins-outputs-email.html) for more information about migration.